# A value of type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'HashMap<String, dynamic>' flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dynamic, hashmap

I am having a `HashMap` of `<String, dynamic>` and i would like to populate the map. The problem i am having is that its telling me the map is not of type dynamic. Below is my code

```
        HashMap<String, dynamic> stuff1 = {"id": 1, "region": "North",
          "shippingAddress": "Flyover", "list": []};
```

How can i create a `HashMap` of `<String, dynamic>`, i know some would suggest using `HashMap<String, Object> stuff` but i am having a `list` like below

```
List<HashMap<String, dynamic>>? stuffList;
```

which has data being populate from a server, but i just want to add `stuff1` to the top of the list and i would like to add it with a `HashMap of <String, dynamic>` because if i add with `<String, Object>` it won't work

Comment: I think you can cast the HashMap to a Map, but not the Map to a HashMap... I believe that's the problem. Try: `List<Map<String, dynamic>>? stuffList;`. If that works, you should be ok. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart `Map` literals (e.g. `{"id": 1, "region": "North", ...}` create objects that conform to the abstract `Map` interface.  By default, the constructed objects are `LinkedHashMap` instances, but the *static* (known at compile-time) type of the literal is just `Map`.

`Map` is the abstract base type for a number of implementations (such as `LinkedHashMap` and `HashMap`).  In general, you cannot directly assign a base type where a derived (more specific) type is expected; that might not be safe.  You also can't just cast the object (which is `LinkedHashMap`) to a `HashMap`; neither `LinkedHashMap` nor `HashMap` derives from the other.

If you *really* want an unordered `HashMap`, you must use a `HashMap` constructor.  For example:

```dart
  HashMap<String, dynamic> stuff1 = HashMap.of({
    "id": 1,
    "region": "North",
    "shippingAddress": "Flyover",
    "list": [],
  });
```

Alternatively consider using a regular `Map` (which, again, by default is a `LinkedHashMap`), which already is hash-based but which additionally maintains insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly instantiate `HashMap`

```dart
final Map<String, dynamic> stuff1 = HashMap()..addAll({"id": 1, "region": "North", "shippingAddress": "Flyover", "list": []});
```

The other solution might be possible is to `as HashMap<String, dynamic>` as the end of `stuff1`

```dart
  Map<String, dynamic> stuff1 = {"id": 1, "region": "North", "shippingAddress": "Flyover", "list": []} as HashMap<String, dynamic>;
```

Comment: A cast will not work.  The constructed `Map` object will be a `LinkedHashMap` instance, which is not directly related to `HashMap`.